# Issues creating new record with Model::create, Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, integer given,

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, models

I have problems to create a new record of Model Llista (in English, List), i think that maybe my structure of Model::create isn't the correct or some field of the model is causing this error.

So i have Listcontroller with this:

**LlistesController.php**

Translations:
(**nom_llista** equals **name_list** and **llista** equals **list**)

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->only('email');
    $nom_llista = $request->only('nom_llista');
    $user = User::where('email', '=',$email)->first();
    $userid = $user->id;
    $llista = Llista::create(array(
         'nom_llista' => $nom_llista,
         'user_id' => $userid)
    );
}
```

`$email`, `$nom_llista`, `$user` and `$userid` I checked and they have the correct values, but on create fails.

Error that throw Laravel doing POST request:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
        <style>
            /* Copyright (c) 2010, Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved. Code licensed under the BSD License: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/license.html */
            html{color:#000;background:#FFF;}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}fieldset,img{border:0;}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}li{list-style:none;}caption,th{text-align:left;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}q:before,q:after{content:'';}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal;}sup{vertical-align:text-top;}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom;}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}input,textarea,select{*font-size:100%;}legend{color:#000;}
            html { background: #eee; padding: 10px }
            img { border: 0; }
            #sf-resetcontent { width:970px; margin:0 auto; }
                        .sf-reset { font: 11px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; color: #333 }
            .sf-reset .clear { clear:both; height:0; font-size:0; line-height:0; }
            .sf-reset .clear_fix:after { display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; }
            .sf-reset .clear_fix { display:inline-block; }
            .sf-reset * html .clear_fix { height:1%; }
            .sf-reset .clear_fix { display:block; }
            .sf-reset, .sf-reset .block { margin: auto }
            .sf-reset abbr { border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; cursor: help; }
            .sf-reset p { font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#868686; padding-bottom:20px }
            .sf-reset strong { font-weight:bold; }
            .sf-reset a { color:#6c6159; cursor: default; }
            .sf-reset a img { border:none; }
            .sf-reset a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
            .sf-reset em { font-style:italic; }
            .sf-reset h1, .sf-reset h2 { font: 20px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif }
            .sf-reset .exception_counter { background-color: #fff; color: #333; padding: 6px; float: left; margin-right: 10px; float: left; display: block; }
            .sf-reset .exception_title { margin-left: 3em; margin-bottom: 0.7em; display: block; }
            .sf-reset .exception_message { margin-left: 3em; display: block; }
            .sf-reset .traces li { font-size:12px; padding: 2px 4px; list-style-type:decimal; margin-left:20px; }
            .sf-reset .block { background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:10px 28px; margin-bottom:20px;
                -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
                -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 16px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 16px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
                border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
                border-right:1px solid #ccc;
                border-left:1px solid #ccc;
            }
            .sf-reset .block_exception { background-color:#ddd; color: #333; padding:20px;
                -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 16px;
                -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 16px;
                -moz-border-radius-topleft: 16px;
                -moz-border-radius-topright: 16px;
                border-top-left-radius: 16px;
                border-top-right-radius: 16px;
                border-top:1px solid #ccc;
                border-right:1px solid #ccc;
                border-left:1px solid #ccc;
                overflow: hidden;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            .sf-reset a { background:none; color:#868686; text-decoration:none; }
            .sf-reset a:hover { background:none; color:#313131; text-decoration:underline; }
            .sf-reset ol { padding: 10px 0; }
            .sf-reset h1 { background-color:#FFFFFF; padding: 15px 28px; margin-bottom: 20px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
                -moz-border-radius: 10px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
                    <div id="sf-resetcontent" class="sf-reset">
                <h1>Whoops, looks like something went wrong.</h1>
                                        <h2 class="block_exception clear_fix">
                            <span class="exception_counter">1/1</span>
                            <span class="exception_title"><abbr title="ErrorException">ErrorException</abbr> in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Grammar.php line 118" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Grammar.php line 118</a>:</span>
                            <span class="exception_message">Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, integer given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 708 and defined</span>
                        </h2>
                        <div class="block">
                            <ol class="traces list_exception">
       <li> in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Grammar.php line 118" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Grammar.php line 118</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions">HandleExceptions</abbr>->handleError('4096', 'Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, integer given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 708 and defined', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Grammar.php', '118', <em>array</em>('this' => <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\MySqlGrammar">MySqlGrammar</abbr>))) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Grammar.php line 118" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Grammar.php line 118</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Grammar">Grammar</abbr>->parameterize('2') in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php line 708" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Grammar.php line 708</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar">Grammar</abbr>->compileInsert(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder">Builder</abbr>), <em>array</em>('nom_llista' => <em>array</em>('nom_llista' => 'Prova'), 'user_id' => '2', 'updated_at' => '2016-06-10 23:52:40', 'created_at' => '2016-06-10 23:52:40')) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php line 726" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Grammar.php line 726</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar">Grammar</abbr>->compileInsertGetId(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder">Builder</abbr>), <em>array</em>('nom_llista' => <em>array</em>('nom_llista' => 'Prova'), 'user_id' => '2', 'updated_at' => '2016-06-10 23:52:40', 'created_at' => '2016-06-10 23:52:40'), 'id') in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php line 2014" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Builder.php line 2014</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder">Builder</abbr>->insertGetId(<em>array</em>('nom_llista' => <em>array</em>('nom_llista' => 'Prova'), 'user_id' => '2', 'updated_at' => '2016-06-10 23:52:40', 'created_at' => '2016-06-10 23:52:40'), 'id')</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func_array(<em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder">Builder</abbr>), 'insertGetId'), <em>array</em>(<em>array</em>('nom_llista' => <em>array</em>('nom_llista' => 'Prova'), 'user_id' => '2', 'updated_at' => '2016-06-10 23:52:40', 'created_at' => '2016-06-10 23:52:40'), 'id')) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php line 1385" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Builder.php line 1385</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder">Builder</abbr>->__call('insertGetId', <em>array</em>(<em>array</em>('nom_llista' => <em>array</em>('nom_llista' => 'Prova'), 'user_id' => '2', 'updated_at' => '2016-06-10 23:52:40', 'created_at' => '2016-06-10 23:52:40'), 'id')) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php line 1621" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Model.php line 1621</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder">Builder</abbr>->insertGetId(<em>array</em>('nom_llista' => <em>array</em>('nom_llista' => 'Prova'), 'user_id' => '2', 'updated_at' => '2016-06-10 23:52:40', 'created_at' => '2016-06-10 23:52:40'), 'id') in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php line 1621" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Model.php line 1621</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model">Model</abbr>->insertAndSetId(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder">Builder</abbr>), <em>array</em>('nom_llista' => <em>array</em>('nom_llista' => 'Prova'), 'user_id' => '2', 'updated_at' => '2016-06-10 23:52:40', 'created_at' => '2016-06-10 23:52:40')) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php line 1590" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Model.php line 1590</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model">Model</abbr>->performInsert(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder">Builder</abbr>), <em>array</em>()) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php line 1481" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Model.php line 1481</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model">Model</abbr>->save() in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php line 571" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Model.php line 571</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model">Model</abbr>::create(<em>array</em>('nom_llista' => <em>array</em>('nom_llista' => 'Prova'), 'user_id' => '2')) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\app\Http\Controllers\LlistesController.php line 54" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">LlistesController.php line 54</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="App\Http\Controllers\LlistesController">LlistesController</abbr>->store(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func_array(<em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="App\Http\Controllers\LlistesController">LlistesController</abbr>), 'store'), <em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>))) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php line 80" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Controller.php line 80</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Controller">Controller</abbr>->callAction('store', <em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>))) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php line 146" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">ControllerDispatcher.php line 146</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher">ControllerDispatcher</abbr>->call(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="App\Http\Controllers\LlistesController">LlistesController</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>), 'store') in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php line 94" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">ControllerDispatcher.php line 94</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher">ControllerDispatcher</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php line 52" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 52</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php line 103" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 103</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->then(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php line 96" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">ControllerDispatcher.php line 96</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher">ControllerDispatcher</abbr>->callWithinStack(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="App\Http\Controllers\LlistesController">LlistesController</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), 'store') in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php line 54" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">ControllerDispatcher.php line 54</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher">ControllerDispatcher</abbr>->dispatch(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), 'App\Http\Controllers\LlistesController', 'store') in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php line 174" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Route.php line 174</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>->runController(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php line 140" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Route.php line 140</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>->run(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php line 724" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Router.php line 724</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Router">Router</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php line 52" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 52</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession">ShareErrorsFromSession</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func_array(<em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession">ShareErrorsFromSession</abbr>), 'handle'), <em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>))) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php line 136" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 136</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php line 32" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 32</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php line 62" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">StartSession.php line 62</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession">StartSession</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func_array(<em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession">StartSession</abbr>), 'handle'), <em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>))) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php line 136" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 136</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php line 32" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 32</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse">AddQueuedCookiesToResponse</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func_array(<em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse">AddQueuedCookiesToResponse</abbr>), 'handle'), <em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>))) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php line 136" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 136</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php line 32" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 32</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php line 59" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">EncryptCookies.php line 59</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies">EncryptCookies</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func_array(<em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies">EncryptCookies</abbr>), 'handle'), <em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>))) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php line 136" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 136</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php line 32" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 32</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php line 103" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 103</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->then(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php line 726" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Router.php line 726</a></li>
    </ol>
</div>

            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Route:**

```
Route::resource('crearllista', 'LlistesController@store', ['only' => [
    'index', 'store'
]]);
```

Comment: Can you please provide the error stack in a more readable format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing nested array to `create` function. Try this

```
$llista = Llista::create(array(
     'nom_llista' => $nom_llista['nom_llista'],
     'user_id' => $userid
));
```